# Can this statement ever evaluate to FALSE?

Tags: c#

I stumbled upon this while doing a review and the author is not available:

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(text);
if (((n > 0) || (n < 0)) || (n == 0))
{
  return 1;
}
```

The code in general looks solid and it's hard for me to believe that the only purpose of this snippet is to confuse reviewers, but I don't see a way for this condition to fail. Am I missing something?

Comment: The code after the if() statement would be interesting.  Does it call Environment.FailFast()?

Comment: What if text is null or something that isn't convertable to a 32-bit integer?

Comment: @JB King: You'll get an exception: `ArgumentNullException`, `FormatException` or `OverflowException`, I think.

Comment: Note that it is not the case that this is always true for doubles and floats; NaNs are not equal to anything, not even themselves.

Comment: Do you have change logs available? Perhaps investigating what else changed in that change set will illuminate what they were thinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be a remnant of a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) type.  See here at msdn for an explanation, but basically if your code was originally this:

```
int? n = StringToInt(text);    // People roll their own functions to do this, though
                               // they really shouldn't
if (((n > 0) || (n < 0)) || (n == 0))
{
  return 1;
}
```

Then this could possibly fall through.  Each of the statements above would be false, as n could be `null` from the function, assuming it returned null on a bad input, and the code supported nullable types.

Unlikely, but when looking at "maintained code" anything is possible.  But as written, it MUST return 1 (or throw an exception, as mentioned by others in this thread).

Comment: This might be it. There are some unused string-manipulation methods in the project.

Comment: Why didn't they just do `if(n.HasValue)` ?

Comment: Nullables are relatively new (.NET 3.0 and up) and still no one would check it that way instead of simply checking (n != null).

Comment: @Danny - nullable types were available in 2.0

Answer (score 5):

It will always return true, assuming it gets there.

Consider:

```
bool x = (n > 0) || (n < 0);
bool y = (n == 0);

if (x || y)
{
    return 1;
}
```

If `n` is not zero then either `n > 0` or `n < 0` is true, so `x` is true and `y` is false.

If `n` is zero, `n == 0` is true, so `x` is false and `y` is true.

Either way, one side of the OR is true.

Comment: So you are saying that really he should just do a `return 1;` without all the `n< n> n==` nonsense?

Comment: @Earlz: Right. If `ToInt32` doesn't throw, the function ends with a `return 1;`. Might as will ditch the tautology.

Comment: @cpalmer yea it can throw? But without the if statement it'd behave the exact same way. It'd just get thrown outside the function.. why is everyone making such a big deal about the can-throw bit.

Comment: @cpalmer: And...? @Earlz: I agree. The question is about the purpose of the logic in the if-statement, obviously we're assuming we got there...

Answer (score 2):

That sure looks like a 100% true statement to me. All those parentheses shouldn't matter in the least, since || is associative, i.e.,

```
(a || b) || c == a || (b || c) == a || b || c
```

Comment: @Dirk DANG. I was afraid I'd screwed that up. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that `int n = Convert.ToInt32(text);` could throw an exception, in which case the if statement never even gets evaluated.

See [Convert.ToInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Which says nothing about the question the OP asked.

Comment: Ahm, I posted that answer first.

Answer (score 1):

If you overload the relational operators for your class, it might be the case that the condition evaluates to `false`, but since `n` is an `int`, it always evaluates to `true`

Comment: +1 for an entirely irrelevant but still interesting mention to operator overloading ;) . I hope to remember that on my next obfuscation project.

Answer (score 0):

As above, it will always be true because, by definition, any real number is either zero, less than zero or greater than zero, and you have covered all cases in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Always will be 1, unless `Convert.ToInt32(text)` throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it can evaluate to false.

If, however, `n` was declared at a different scope where more than a single thread had access to it and one of these threads changes its value, theres quite a high chance the condition would fail.

Answer (score 0):

it will always be true as you write all the states it might be (e.g < > ==)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it could also throw an exception if the conversion fails :-)

Comment: In that case, the if-statement will never be evaluated.